# How can I start/stop applications on a different computer?

Tags: c#, communication, cross-process

Is it possible for one C# (desktop) application to start and stop applications on another machine?

I don't mean in a malicious sense, or even over the internet. I have two computers in a room and I need an app on one to start (and then stop) and app on the other.

One half-formed route in my mind was to use an auxiliary program on the target computer, so I suppose I ought to point out that I am completely able to make any necessary changes to either machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can do changes there are so many possibilities!

- WMI : Never tried that out but given sufficient rights you should be able to start processes, or at least services on a remote machine
- .NET remoting: Somewhat old, but easy to implement
- WCF
- HttpListener
- Private Message Queues (that's what I did once)
- ?

Most of the alternatives involve writing a small service that listens on the communication technique of your choice and then starts a process or does something else.

Answer (score 2):

An example using WMI is up on Code Project:

> **[Create a Remote Process using WMI in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Remote_Process_using_WMI_.aspx)**

But probably in your case a simple `PsExec.exe` call might be enough, e.g.

```
Process.Start("psexec.exe", "\\remotehost -u user -p password calc.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

psexec.exe from sysinternals or Use Powershell 2.0 and WMI